# Working with UISearchBar Filterable TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am pretty new in objective c so hopefully this all make sense.I have followed this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2yaZXn4MU0) tutorial from YouTube.The program is not working .
You can download the project from this [link](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gf87581e0cec15aae999483436dd57eaeeb4eb07fa).Guide me 
to make this program functional.

Comment: u want search the content in search bar using uitableview

Comment: yes..i want to search the content in search bar in uitableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view controller.h file

## import

```
@interface RecipeBookViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 
{

  NSArray *recipes;   //this is used for load the data to table
   NSArray *searchResults; //this is used for search the particular name in uitableview
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;    //progrmatically allocationg the tableview
```

.m file

```
@synthesize tableView;  //this is used accessing the name in more than one time


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Initialize table data

searchResults=[NSArray alloc]init];

recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

//create the tableview
tableView =[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 163, 320, 317)];
tableView.delegate=self;
tableView.dataSource=self;
[self. tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

[self.view addSubview: tableView];

}


//this is for loading the table data

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];

} else {
    return [recipes count];

}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}

//this is for search bar delegate method for filtering

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods
 -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
 shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
 {
 [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:   [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}
```

finally add the one search bar display controller only in top on the view

Comment: try this , any queries, reply o me

Comment: Simply pasting the code on view-controller display the tableview  ...When I added the search bar ....I set the outlet delegate connected with files owner ...and reference outlet view to file owner..it is not displaying search bar ..

Comment: just add the search bar and display controller, don't give the outlet, it automatically detected bro

Comment: If i simply add search bar to viewcontroller ..The execution stops with exception of :     test[1170:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "TESTBIDViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:           ........................................

Comment: u were copy paste my code, its k , just change the .h file TESTBIDViewController replaced to RecipeBookViewController

Comment: The search bar is not performing Search operation on tableview... Please help

Comment: can u send ur code for my mail id karthik.saral@gmail.com

Comment: Code sent ...file name is ..  :test.zip.....I require exactly same behavior as in RecipeBook...like cancel button in search bar black screen during typing in search bar...

Comment: gt brother, will u need any assistance cal my mail id, gt

Answer (score 1):

use the following tutorial is the simple way to get the answer and and also u get the sample code in github, the link is   http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: its not a mean, u mean only the view controllers, just customize the coding , if u r select the cell in did select row, that time u need to allocate the view controllers and push the object, its simple

Comment: If it is simple to convert this tutorial to xib ..kindly upload it only for functionality of search the content in search bar using uitableview ..Because i am just initial learner ..

Comment: hmm , k k , just wait

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;                     // called when text starts editing
{
    if (searching)
    {
        searching=YES;
        letsUserSelectRow=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        searching=NO;
        letsUserSelectRow=YES;
    }
    // self.tbl_searchtable.scrollEnabled=NO;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
{
    searching = NO;
    letsUserSelectRow = YES;
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tbl_searchuser reloadData];
}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView :(UITableView *)theTableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(letsUserSelectRow)
        return indexPath;
    else
        return nil;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;   // called when text changes (including clear)
{
    _tbl_searchuser.hidden=FALSE;

    [copylistofitem removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] > 0)
    {
        searching = YES;
        letsUserSelectRow = YES;
        self.tbl_searchuser.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [self searchtableview];
    }
    else
    {
        searching = NO;
        letsUserSelectRow= NO;
        [_searchbar resignFirstResponder];
        //self.tbl_searchtable.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }

    [copylistofitem retain];
    [self.tbl_searchuser reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;                     // called when keyboard search button pressed
{
    [self hide];
    //[self searchtableview];
}

-(void)searchtableview
{
    _tbl_searchuser.frame=CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 140);
    NSString *searchText = _searchbar.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",array_allusers);
    for(int l = 0; l < [array_allusers count]; l++)
    {
        NSString *tempstr = [[array_allusers objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"username"];
        NSRange rngstr = [tempstr rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];

        if(rngstr.length > 0)
        {
            [copylistofitem addObject:[array_allusers objectAtIndex:l]];
            [copylistofitem retain];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",copylistofitem);

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"username" ascending:YES];
    [copylistofitem sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [_tbl_searchuser reloadData];










}
-(void)hide
{
    [_searchbar resignFirstResponder];
    _tbl_searchuser.frame=CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 274);

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (searching && [_searchbar.text length] > 0)
        return [copylistofitem count];
    else
        return yourarray;

}

NSMutableArray *copylistofitem;
BOOL searching;
BOOL letsUserSelectRow;
```